# How to retrieve the dynamic value in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create the test cases using Selenium WebDriver with Java.  I have the following HTML syntax in the source.

```
<label for="00N30000005wfev"><span class=class="requiredMark">*</span>Type</label>
<select id="00N30000005wfev" tabindex="34" name="00N30000005wfev">
<option value="Account">Account</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Service">Service</option>
</select>
```

All the "for","id" and "name" value are dynamically generated when the application creates a new item every time. The label name is fixed for the item details. How can I dynamically retrieve this value based on the label name value (e.g. Type)?

When Java runs, it will look at the "Type" label first, then it will be able to find the "for" value.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a XPath expression to do this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Type')]"));
String labelForValue = element.getAttribute("for");
```

Comment: You need a couple more lines of code in order to get the selected value: `WebElement selectedOption = driver.getElementById(labelForValue).getFirstSelectedOption();` then you can fetch the value with `String selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.getText();`